# Symfony2: How to create own translation files?

Tags: translation, symfony

I want to create my own translation file. For Example I want a "`my-application.en_EN.yml`" in my tranlsations folder in Ressources in my Bundle.

When I do this, the translation in my file does not work.
Only when I name the file like the standard name "`messages.en_EN.yml`" then it works.

But how can I have my own namings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`messages.{language}.yml` is the default name of translation files (in `YML` format), Symfony will load the translation file automatically and provide translations in all the contexts.

It's different if the translation file has a different name, in this case you have to add the first part of the file name (the translation [domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations)) as an argument when translating a string:

In a Controller:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('my.message', array(), 'my-application');
```

In a Twig template:

```
{{ 'my.message'|trans({}, 'my-application') }}
```

See the official documentation for further information:

- [Translations (The Symfony Book)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations)
- [The Translation Component (The Symfony Components)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations)